# Codeigniter this->db->group_by date from timestamp format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to show a `select` query and grouping them by `date`.
My query:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN status >= 4 THEN 1 END) as success, created_on FROM pickup GROUP BY (Date(created_on))
```

Query above produce the result as I expected

```html
$this->load->model('pickup_model');

        $this->db->select("COUNT(CASE WHEN status >= 4 THEN 1 END) AS success, pickup.created_on");
        $this->db->group_by("pickup.created_on");
```

`created_on` field is `timestamp` format but I need to convert it to `date` format, I don't know how to use that query in codeigniter, and I cannot just `$this->db->group_by("created_on");` because I took it from the model and joining some table. I am wondering if it has something to do with alias?

I tried with:

1. `$this->db->group_by(DATE("pickup.created_on")):`
2. `$this->db->group_by(date('Y-m-d', strtotime ('pickup.created_on')):`
3. `$this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN status >= 4 THEN 1 END) as success, created_on FROM pickup GROUP BY (Date('pickup.created_on'))");`

none of the above work

Comment: you mind pasting full function / Active-record query you are using? group_by works on timestamp formats and default is ascending order.

Comment: Sorry for partial of above comment, my mind was referring to order_by actually. Have you tried group_by in the same select statement instead of grouping it separately

Comment: yes, I did. but it didn't work. let me edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Alright I have simulated your case like this

[image]

Convert it into CI

```
$this->db->select('count(ID) from pickup WHERE status >4) as success, created_on')->from('pickup')->group_by('created_on')->get()->result_array();
```

Hope that will solve your problem, change any name of table or field as per your db schema if needed.

Comment: I have this following error `Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as success, `created_on` FROM `pickup` GROUP BY `pickup`.`created_on`, `created_' at line 1`

Comment: as per MariaDB knowledge base https://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/alias.php I think you need to replace as with AS

Comment: still getting the same error :(
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS success, `

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select("pickup.created_on");
$this->db->select("COUNT(CASE WHEN status >= 4 THEN 1 END) AS success",FALSE);
$this->db->group_by("pickup.created_on");
```

> Hope it's work for you.

Comment: I did it, but it returns all the row, I think it's because the timestamp field `created_on` contain different value on every row